# Как сгенерировать HTML страницы документации по XML комментариям?

Tags: документация, поиск-программ

Как сгенерировать документацию по Xml комментариям?

DocFX, пишут, что может это делать, но не найду мануала как подключать XML документацию к нему, чтобы она автоматически генерировалась в HTML страницы сайта.

Какие еще средства можно использовать для этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой мануал для DocFX есть здесь: https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/walkthrough/walkthrough_create_a_docfx_project_2.html

Чтобы подключить XML-документацию к сайту DocFX, нужно добавить в источники либо *.csproj проекта (чтобы документация бралась из исходников), либо собранные файлы *.dll (чтобы документация бралась из *.xml файлов, сгенерированных компилятором рядом с DLL). Первый способ обычно лучше, но он требует установленной Visual Studio 2019 на машине, где осуществляется сборка документации, даже если сам проект создан в более старой версии.

Вот пример docfx.json с использованием XML-документации:

```
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      "src": [
        {
          "files": ["*.dll"],          
          "src": "MyLib/bin/Debug/"
        }
      ],
      "dest": "api"      
    }
  ],
  "build": {
    "content": [
      {
        "files": [
          "api/**.yml",
          "api/index.md"
        ]
      },
      {
        "files": [
          "articles/**.md",
          "articles/**/toc.yml",
          "toc.yml",
          "*.md"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "resource": [
      {
        "files": [
          "images/**"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "overwrite": [
      {
        "files": [
          "apidoc/**.md"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "obj/**",
          "_site/**"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "dest": "docs",
    "globalMetadata": {
      "_appTitle": "My Lib"
    },
    "globalMetadataFiles": [],
    "fileMetadataFiles": [],
    "template": [
      "default"
    ],
    "postProcessors": [],
    "markdownEngineName": "markdig",
    "noLangKeyword": false,
    "keepFileLink": false    
  }
}
```

Здесь исходными данными для документации являются файлы XML для всех DLL из каталога `MyLib/bin/Debug/`, файлы .md из каталога articles и изображения из каталога images. (Несмотря на то, что в json исходными файлами считается DLL, на самом деле информация будет браться из XML-файлов.)

Для генерации на основе проекта секцию metadata нужно будет поменять так:

```
"metadata": [
    {
      "src": [
        {
          "files": [
            "MyLib/**.csproj"
          ],
          "exclude": [
            "**/bin/**",
            "**/obj/**"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "dest": "api"
    }
  ]
```